# Group data by single column but want to show them as column

Tags: mysql

I am working on my small project in which I have a situation in which, we need to show report like below:

```
gender    gender_count    rejected     selected  
Male      230             50           180  
Female    150             20           130
```

All values in above report(excluding gender column) are count from table.

Table structure is given below:

```
 user_id     gender    status  
 1           male      selected  
 2           male      selected  
 3           female    rejected  
 4           female    selected  
 5           male      rejected
```

I am not able to write query for this kind of report. I was using group by to count gender. but how can I count gender by status and then make them as column.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've provided the answer below...check it and update me...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
GENDER, COUNT(*) GENDER_COUNT, 
SUM(IF(STATUS='REJECTED',1,0)) REJECTED,
SUM(IF(STATUS='SELECTED',1,0)) SELECTED
FROM 
TABLE
GROUP BY GENDER
```

Other DBs you would need to use `CASE` instead of `IF`

(I am not a MySQL expert but this should point you in the right way)

Comment: You would need to use: `UPPER(STATUS)='REJECTED'` or `STATUS='rejected'` instead.

Comment: Ah, MySQL - always full of surprises. :)  Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(*) gender_count, SUM(status='rejected') rejected, 
       SUM(status='selected') selected 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked through SQLfiddle and the link is provided below you can check it...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/822019/3

```
 CREATE TABLE table1 (
        user_id int,
        gender varchar(255),
        status varchar(255)

    );

    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,"male","selected"),
    (2,"male","selected"),
    (3,"female","rejected"),
    (4,"female","selected"),
    (5,"male","rejected");

SELECT
gender, COUNT(*) GENDER_COUNT, 
SUM(IF(STATUS='REJECTED',1,0)) REJECTED,
SUM(IF(STATUS='SELECTED',1,0)) SELECTED
FROM 
table1
GROUP BY gender
```

Comment: I think this will help you to solve your problem...try this query and update me...

Answer (score 0):

for your case

```
 mysql> select   * from genderlist;
    +---------+--------+--------+
    | user_id | gender | status |
    +---------+--------+--------+
    |       1 | male   | select |
    |       2 | female | select |
    |       3 | female | reject |
    |       4 | female | reject |
    |       5 | male   | reject |
    |       6 | male   | select |
    +---------+--------+--------+
```

try the below query

> SELECT gender,count(*) as gendercount,sum(status='select') as 'selected',sum(status='reject') as reject from genderlist group by gender;

output will be

```
mysql> SELECT gender,count(*) as gendercount,sum(status='select') as 'selected',sum(status='reject') as reject from genderlist group by gender;
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+
| gender | gendercount | selected | reject |
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+
| female |           3 |        1 |      2 |
| male   |           3 |        2 |      1 |
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+
```